# Numpy boolean index mask for conditional subtraction of existing values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I have a numpy array of numbers in the range (0, 180). For each of those values, if the value *x* is larger than 90, I want to replace it with 180 - *x* .

e.g. 5 -> 5, 50 -> 50, 100 -> 80, 175 -> 5.

Since the power of numpy is in its ability to operate on the whole array at once, e.g. a = a + 1 to increment all items in a by 1, I tried the following using a boolean mask:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.randint(180, size=(20))
>>> a
array([150, 136,  28,  77,   7, 165, 114,  71, 150,  86, 129, 156,  33,
        34,  91,  87, 105,   9,   5, 108])
>>> a[a > 90] = 180 - a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 20 input values to the 10 output values where the mask is true
>>>
```

This fails because there is a mismatch in the length of the mask array and the original array. 
How can I do it (without resorting to iterating through the array manually)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> a
array([172,  47,  58,  47, 162, 130,  16, 173, 125,  40,  25,  32, 123,
       142,  89,  29, 120,   2,  97, 116])
>>> np.where(a>90, 180-a, a)
array([ 8, 47, 58, 47, 18, 50, 16,  7, 55, 40, 25, 32, 57, 38, 89, 29, 60,
        2, 83, 64])
```

Note that this returns a new array, rather than modifying the existing array.  You can assign it back to `a` if you want, but the change will not be "seen" by any other variables that were referencing the original array.

You can also do what you did, if you select the appropriate elements on both sides of the assignment:

```
>>> a[a>90] = 180 - a[a>90]
>>> a
array([ 8, 47, 58, 47, 18, 50, 16,  7, 55, 40, 25, 32, 57, 38, 89, 29, 60,
        2, 83, 64])
```

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the first method and what you mentioned about changes not being be seen by other variables, if the new array is assigned back to a;  Do you simply mean, if you already calculated them from a before the update? In this case I would naturally expect to have to recalculate them in order to take account of the changes in a!

Comment: @feedMe: I just mean, if you do `a = numpy.random.randint(...)` and then do `b = a`, and then do `a = np.where(...)`, this will not affect `b`, whereas the second method (`a[a>90] = ...`) will.  This is not specific to numpy but is sometimes a gotcha for people unfamiliar with how Python works.